# Exception handling in Selenium, how to iterate through a bunch of element locators until one works

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, try-catch

The id of a button I want to click is changing dynamically. For example the id will be id = Button7 then the next time I run my code it is id = Button19. I noticed it loops through a set of ids but in no particular order.

I would like to iterate through all possible solutions until one of them works. Would like to do something similar to this logic.

```
    try:
        source8 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xl_dijit-bootstrap_Button_99"]')
        ActionChains(driver).click(source8).perform()
    except Exception as e:
        source8 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xl_dijit-bootstrap_Button_7"]')
        ActionChains(driver).click(source8).perform()
    except Exception as e:
        source8 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xl_dijit-bootstrap_Button_27"]')
        ActionChains(driver).click(source8).perform()
```

Comment: Except the ID what are the other properties that button has, we need to find the uniqueness of the element before doing any operation, the concept of iterating by changing id's may click other elements which are similar to that. Post the snippet of source code or URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the xpaths:

```
for xpath in ['//xpath1', '//hpath2', '//xpath3']:
  try:
    # do something with xpath
    break
  except:
   print(xpath + " failed!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use contains XPath axes to detect the ID first and then do necessary actions.

```
elementId = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'xl_dijit-bootstrap_Button_')]")

elementId.click()
```

Else if you wish to do some other action with a specific ID then retrieve it's attribute and with this attribute('idTextAttribute') you can implement a switch case.

```
idTextAttribute = elementId.get_attribute("id")

    def SwitchToId(idTextAttribute):
        switcher = {
            "xl_dijit-bootstrap_Button_99": Do Something, like click Or sendKeys,
            "xl_dijit-bootstrap_Button_7": Do Something, like click Or sendKeys,
            "xl_dijit-bootstrap_Button_27": Do Something, like click Or sendKeys,
        }
        return switcher.get(idTextAttribute, "ID not Found")
```

Note: Python doesn't have a switch case like Java so you can try switcher or if-elif block.